# Seeing copy and pasted formatting

Tags: javascript, rtf

If I have a google doc with styling (bold, underline, etc), is there a way to parse the formatting with Javascript? I am trying to make an extremely simple WYSWIG -> HTML formatter, and easily was able to substitute whitespace with HTML, but am having a harder time with formatting.

TL/DR: If I copy and paste from a Google Doc to a textarea, can I use Javascript to see what the formatting was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a textbox, which will remove all formatting, you can use HTML5's `contenteditable` property.

```
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true">
edit me
</div>
```

If you paste something into that box, it will preserve formatting. Now you can use jQuery's `.html()` to get the HTML of the container.

```
$("#editable").html()
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a8YMC/)